# Cannot run quarkus test on gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, quarkus

Everything works on my machine. Problem is when I run tests on gitlab CI i get this error :

```
AuthenticationResourceTest > signinuser exists => returns a jwt token FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at QuarkusTestExtension.java:626
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
            Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException at CompletableFuture.java:314
                Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at TestResourceManager.java:457
                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:15
```

As my project is using Lombok could this be related to it? (but why does it work on my machine???).

Here is my .gitlab-ci:

```yaml
stages:         
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  image: openjdk:16
  script: ./gradlew --build-cache quarkusBuild
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: push
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle

test:
  stage: test
  image: openjdk:16
  script: ./gradlew check
  artifacts:
    name: coverage
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/jacoco-report
    reports:
      junit: jacoco.xml
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
```

Really struggling here.

Comment: What does this test failure mean, `AuthenticationResourceTest > signinuser exists => returns a jwt token FAILED` ?

Comment: This was my test name. It failed directly running any test.

Answer (score 3):

Found the error.
Forgot that testcontainer needs docker dind

For those who struggle with this: test containers needs to run a docker container in order to create a test database.
That's the purpose of the dind service (docker in docker).

from
https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/gitlab_ci/

Here is a sample .gitlab-ci.yml that executes test with gradle:

```
# DinD service is required for Testcontainers
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    # explicitly disable tls to avoid docker startup interruption
    command: ["--tls=false"]

variables:
  # Instruct Testcontainers to use the daemon of DinD.
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  # Instruct Docker not to start over TLS.
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  # Improve performance with overlayfs.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

test:
 image: gradle:5.0
 stage: test
 script: ./gradlew test
```